# Java - Can't seem to draw text on screen following the path of an equation

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm constructing the basis of a game and when the character hits an NPC, I want a number to float around the player for a second or two. The problem I'm having is when I try to draw the number following a parabolic equation, all that gets drawn is the number in a diagonal line, as seen below.

[image: fig. 1]

The equation I want it to follow is `x^2/50 + 2x`, from x=0 to x=100.

Here is the code I've made.

```
for(int x=0; x<100; x++) {
    g.drawString("5", x, ((x^2)/50) + (2*x));
}
```

I've adjusted the equation in multiple ways so that the line is wider and skinnier, but still having no luck. Any ideas about where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Are you asking why the number is not animated or why you are not getting a parabola?

Comment: Why I'm not getting a parabola.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is why are you not getting a parabola, the reason is that in Java the way you say "x squared" is

```
x * x
```

and not

```
x ^ 2
```

The later does a binary exclusive or with 2.  Not what you want.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I wasn't aware of this in Java. Works just as expected now :)

Comment: Cool. Many languages have a power operator, such as `**` in Python and Ruby, and `^` in Lua.  Unfortunately (or fortunately for some people), Java does not have one.